# Add Margin to a custom UI Table Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm fairly new to the native app dev world and predominately a Front-End Dev/designer - I have built a IOS7 app in Xcode 5 - which contains a UITable with several custom cells.  I would like to add margin of approx 8px to each of the cells (to look like the image below) - and change the colour of the link arrow which appears via a push segue - but have no idea how to do either despite a good web search / book read - theres doesnt seem to be the relevant options on the storyboard.

Can anyone advice if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code goes like this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for add margin of each cell (this code add margin only to top of each cell):

```
UIView *separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 8)];
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

and for color of arrow you have to create an image and insert it with this code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 7, 11)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]]];
 cell.accessoryView = label;
```

Comment: thanks llario - Does this get applied to each custom class or the containing table

Comment: @Paul This code also applies to custom cell, just change the name "cell" with your customNameCell

Answer (score 2):

You can include a margin to the cell by resizing the table itself. Instead of the standard 320 pixels width, change the width of the table to 312. That will give you an overall margin without having to meddle with the internals of the table view.

```
CGFloat margin = 8;    
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width-margin, self.view.frame.height);
```

In order to change the color of the arrow, you have to change what's called the `accessoryView` of the `UITableViewCell`. It can be any `UIView`.

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredArrow.png"]];
```

Comment: In my case it works in 50%: margins are added but they also cover table content. Thus in my case I lost roundings on left side of rows.